# Understanding the -exec option of `find`

Tags: shell, find

I find myself constantly looking up the syntax of

```
find . -name "FILENAME"  -exec rm {} \;
```

mainly because I don't see how exactly the `-exec` part works. What is the meaning of the braces, the backslash and the semicolon? Are there other use cases for that syntax?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This answer comes in the following parts:

- Basic usage of `-exec`
- Using `-exec` in combination with `sh -c`
- Using `-exec ... {} +`
- Using `-execdir`

---

### Basic usage of `-exec`

The `-exec` option takes an external utility with optional arguments as its argument and executes it.

If the string `{}` is present anywhere in the given command, each instance of it will be replaced by the pathname currently being processed (e.g. `./some/path/FILENAME`).  In most shells, the two characters `{}` does not need to be quoted.

The command needs to be terminated with a `;` for `find` to know where it ends (as there may be further options afterwards).  To protect the `;` from the shell, it needs to be quoted as `\;` or `';'`, otherwise the shell will see it as the end of the `find` command.

Example (the `\` at the end of the first two lines are just for line continuations):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt'      \
   -exec grep -q 'hello' {} ';'   \
   -exec cat {} ';'
```

This will find all regular files (`-type f`) whose names matches the pattern `*.txt` in or below the current directory.  It will then test whether the string `hello` occurs in any of the found files using `grep -q` (which does not produce any output, just an exit status).  For those files that contain the string, `cat` will be executed to output the contents of the file to the terminal.

Each `-exec` also acts like a "test" on the pathnames found by `find`, just like `-type` and `-name` does. If the command returns a zero exit status (signifying "success"), the next part of the `find` command is considered, otherwise the `find` command continues with the next pathname.  This is used in the example above to find files that contain the string `hello`, but to ignore all other files.

The above example illustrates the two most common use cases of `-exec`:

1. As a test to further restrict the search.
2. To perform some kind of action on the found pathname (usually, but not necessarily, at the end of the `find` command).

---

### Using `-exec` in combination with `sh -c`

The command that `-exec` can execute is limited to an external utility with optional arguments. To use shell built-ins, functions, conditionals, pipelines, redirections etc. directly with `-exec` is not possible, unless wrapped in something like a `sh -c` child shell.

If `bash` features are required, then use `bash -c` in place of `sh -c`.

`sh -c` runs `/bin/sh` with a script given on the command line, followed by optional command line arguments to that script.

A simple example of using `sh -c` by itself, without `find`:

```
sh -c 'echo  "You gave me $1, thanks!"' sh "apples"
```

This passes two arguments to the child shell script. These will be placed in `$0` and `$1` for the script to use.

1. The string `sh`.  This will be available as `$0` inside the script, and if the internal shell outputs an error message, it will prefix it with this string.
2. The argument `apples` is available as `$1` in the script, and had there been more arguments, then these would have been available as `$2`, `$3` etc.  They would also be available in the list `"$@"` (except for `$0` which would not be part of `"$@"`).

This is useful in combination with `-exec` as it allows us to make arbitrarily complex scripts that acts on the pathnames found by `find`.

Example: Find all regular files that have a certain filename suffix, and change that filename suffix to some other suffix, where the suffixes are kept in variables:

```
from=text  #  Find files that have names like something.text
to=txt     #  Change the .text suffix to .txt

find . -type f -name "*.$from" -exec sh -c 'mv "$3" "${3%.$1}.$2"' sh "$from" "$to" {} ';'
```

Inside the internal script, `$1` would be the string `text`, `$2` would be the string `txt` and `$3` would be whatever pathname `find` has found for us.  The parameter expansion `${3%.$1}` would take the pathname and remove the suffix `.text` from it.

Or, using `dirname`/`basename`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.$from" -exec sh -c '
    mv "$3" "$(dirname "$3")/$(basename "$3" ".$1").$2"' sh "$from" "$to" {} ';'
```

or, with added variables in the internal script:

```
find . -type f -name "*.$from" -exec sh -c '
    from=$1; to=$2; pathname=$3
    mv "$pathname" "$(dirname "$pathname")/$(basename "$pathname" ".$from").$to"' sh "$from" "$to" {} ';'
```

Note that in this last variation, the variables `from` and `to` in the child shell are distinct from the variables with the same names in the external script.

The above is the correct way of calling an arbitrary complex script from `-exec` with `find`.  Using `find` in a loop like

```
for pathname in $( find ... ); do
```

is error prone and inelegant (personal opinion). It is splitting filenames on whitespaces, invoking filename globbing, and also forces the shell to expand the complete result of `find` before even running the first iteration of the loop.

See also:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)

---

### Using `-exec ... {} +`

The `;` at the end may be replaced by `+`.  This causes `find` to execute the given command with as many arguments (found pathnames) as possible rather than once for each found pathname.  *The string `{}`  has to occur just before the `+` for this to work*.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' \
   -exec grep -q 'hello' {} ';' \
   -exec cat {} +
```

Here, `find` will collect the resulting pathnames and execute `cat` on as many of them as possible at once.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" \
   -exec grep -q "hello" {} ';' \
   -exec mv -t /tmp/files_with_hello/ {} +
```

Likewise here, `mv` will be executed as few times as possible. This last example requires GNU `mv` from coreutils (which supports the `-t` option).

Using `-exec sh -c ... {} +` is also an efficient way to loop over a set of pathnames with an arbitrarily complex script.

The basics is the same as when using `-exec sh -c ... {} ';'`, but the script now takes a much longer list of arguments.  These can be looped over by looping over `"$@"` inside the script.

Our example from the last section that changes filename suffixes:

```
from=text  #  Find files that have names like something.text
to=txt     #  Change the .text suffix to .txt

find . -type f -name "*.$from" -exec sh -c '
    from=$1; to=$2
    shift 2  # remove the first two arguments from the list
             # because in this case these are *not* pathnames
             # given to us by find
    for pathname do  # or:  for pathname in "$@"; do
        mv "$pathname" "${pathname%.$from}.$to"
    done' sh "$from" "$to" {} +
```

---

### Using `-execdir`

There is also `-execdir` (implemented by most `find` variants, but not a standard option).

This works like `-exec` with the difference that the given shell command is executed with the directory of the found pathname as its current working directory and that `{}` will contain the basename of the found pathname without its path (but GNU `find` will still prefix the basename with `./`, while BSD `find` or `sfind` won't).

Example:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -execdir mv -- {} 'done-texts/{}.done' \;
```

This will move each found `*.txt`-file to a pre-existing `done-texts` subdirectory *in the same directory as where the file was found*.  The file will also be renamed by adding the suffix `.done` to it. `--`, to mark the end of options is needed here in those `find` implementations that don't prefix the basename with `./`. The quotes around the argument that contains `{}` not as a whole are needed if your shell is `(t)csh`. Also note that not all `find` implementations will expand that `{}` there (`sfind` won't).

This would be a bit trickier to do with `-exec` as we would have to get the basename of the found file out of `{}` to form the new name of the file. We also need the directory name from `{}` to locate the `done-texts` directory properly.

With `-execdir`, some things like these becomes easier.

The corresponding operation using `-exec` instead of `-execdir` would have to employ a child shell:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        mv "$name" "$( dirname "$name" )/done-texts/$( basename "$name" ).done"
    done' sh {} +
```

or,

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        mv "$name" "${name%/*}/done-texts/${name##*/}.done"
    done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Saying it's a shell command is wrong here, `find -exec cmd arg \;` doesn't invoke a shell to interpret a shell command line, it runs `execlp("cmd", "arg")` directly, not `execlp("sh", "-c", "cmd arg")` (for which the shell would end up doing the equivalent of `execlp("cmd", "arg")` if `cmd` was not builtin).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I tried to not be too technical at the start. This is clarified (I hope) by the "footnote". I will adjust it to "external utility".

Comment: You could clarify that all the `find` arguments after `-exec` and up to `;` or `+` make up the command to execute along with its arguments, with each instance of a `{}` argument replaced with the current file (with `;`), and `{}` as the last argument before `+` replaced with a list of files as separate arguments (in the `{} +` case). IOW `-exec` takes _several_ arguments, terminated by a `;` or `{}` `+`.

Comment: @Kusalananda , I find my self in need of understanding the `-exec` and `execdir` options of `find`, so excuse me for commenting on an old answer but I have a question. In your example for `-execdir`, how are you guaranteeing that the subdirectory `done-texts` exist in the same directory where a `.txt` file is found? Or is your reasoning that `-exec` will exit with a non zero failure status when the subdirectory `done-texts` is not in the same directory as a `.txt` file meaning `.txt` files will only be moved by `mv` when the `done-texts` subdirectory is in the same directory as a `.txt` file?

Comment: @Kusalananda Wouldn't your last example also work with this simpler command : `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c "mv $1 $(dirname $1)/done-texts/$(basename $1).done" sh {} ';'` ?

Comment: @Atralb Yes, that would also have worked and had the same effect as the last piece of code, but instead of running `mv` in a loop, once per found file, you execute both `sh` and `mv` for each found file, which will be noticeably slower for large amounts of files.

Comment: Optimization: Reverse the order of the predicates `-type f -name '*.txt'` to be `-name '*.txt' -type f`. Doing so would avoid applying `-type f` "which potentially involves an extra expensive `lstat()` system call" when name does not match `*.txt`, per [answer to a different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611691).

Comment: Very nice answer. For the last example, is it the same if we use `;` instead of `+` and without the for-loop? That is `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'mv "$name" "${name%/*}/done-texts/${name##*/}.done"' sh {} ';'`. What are the differences?

Comment: @midnite You would need to use `$1` in place of `$name`. Other than that, it would be _functionally_ equivalent but would start `sh -c` once for each found name rather than batching found names and running `sh -c` as few times as possible.

Comment: If the final `sh` can be any text, or indeed any value, just to displace the rest to `$1`+, why is it almost always `sh`? I find using `sh` here confusing as it looks like a shell invocation, as if `$0` must be an executable.

Comment: @Chris That string is used in error messages that the `sh -c` shell may produce. Making it the string `sh` or `find-sh` or some similar string is common to be able to distinguish diagnostic output from that `sh -c` shell invocation from any other diagnostic output that a script (or the utilities used in a script) might possibly produce.

Comment: Thanks very much, it all suddenly makes sense!